# How can I achieve a near constant FPS with QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have subclassed `QOpenGLWidget`.
I use the following surface format:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
format.setSwapInterval(2); // every 2nd vsync
```

Using this surface format I do not have to call `update()`.
Instead Qt will call my `paintGL()` at the refresh rate of my monitor (60 Hz) divided by my `swapInterval` (2).

So in theory I should get a constant FPS=30. However when I measure this the FPS vary a lot:

[image]

I measure the time at the start of `paintGL()` with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`, find the elapsed miliseconds since last call to `paintGL()` and divide 1000 by this to get the FPS.

My `paintGL()` method always take less than 1 ms to complete.
My GPU seem to be hardly breaking a sweat:
[image]

My CPU also seem to be fine although there are some spikes in CPU 2 and 4 utilization:
[image]

What can I do to achieve a near constant FPS with `QOpenGLWidget`?

BTW. Calling `format.setSwapInterval()` does not seem to have any effect. If I try to set the `swapInterval` to 1, the FPS still fluctates around 30 and not 60 as I would expect.

Comment: How do you measure your FPS? Have you checked your CPU/GPU usage during the usage?

Comment: To achieve a constant FPS on a non-RT-OS (like e.g. Windows) is not that simple in general. (Occasional glitches might be acceptable and might appear rarely if the PC is not under too heavy load.) However, to do it with Qt is even harder. Qt is simply not designed for this. (I'm telling you this as a developer of 3d vis. sim. application implemented in Qt / OpenGL who periodically discusses about FPS measurements made by colleagues and customers.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: thank you. Is the main point to keep the CPU load low? No other programs need to run on the PC. Say I manage to keep it constant below say 5% would that help? Will setting the priority of my program to High or Realtime help? How about minimizing the use of signal slots and instead running as much as possible in a separate thread?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can give you valuable hints. In our case, I convinced the colleagues that accuracy of the simulation has to be the primary goal and a quite fluid visualization is at best welcome. Hence, I do the sim. in a separate thread where I carefully try to match the required timing feeding the visualization with a cycle buffer facility (which I once learnt from SGI software). I added a statistics feature to produce similar graphs like your, and I must admit that they even look similar like yours (with these annoying spikes here and there). ...

Comment: ...  I convinced my colleagues that there isn't much that we can do about this although I still have hope to achieve an improvement one day. The attempts I already tried (again having in mind what I learnt in the past from SGI) were fruitless so far. Maybe, there would be an improvement to exploit OS specific features of Windows but I'm still sticking to the idea to stay portable. So, I live with this for now and it seems it isn't finally that show stopper (even not for the customers) that would us force to investigate harder. Again: Windows is not an RT-OS. Hence, I haven't high expectations.

Comment: @Scheff: I use a texture as a cycle buffer. My simulation runs in a separate thread, locks a mutex, glTexSubImage2D() the data to the texture and unlocks the mutex. My paintGL locks the mutex, paints using the uploaded texture and unlocks the mutex.

Comment: Ah, yes. Our sim. is completely free of Qt. It's just plain C++ code based on what `<thread>` and `<chrono>` offer. ;-)

Comment: I actually used cycle buffers because I tried to prevent mutex guarding. Each thread has its buffer for its exclusive usage. The swapping is done using atomic pointers. (I hope I didn't introduce a data race. According to what I learnt so far I have done it correctly and introduce the necessary fences and barriers. Though, this is a hot topic, and it's easy to fail but hard to recognize the effects reliably and reproducible.) However, first I would try to identify whether the locking is the issue in quest, at all. No need to repair what's not broken. ;-) It's a difficult topic at all...